# Odoo Modify or extend import process

Tags: import, odoo, action

I want modify or extend the process on csv import in Odoo.

I have some fields autocalculated and other needed but is not in the csv file.

Having search the code and try using ir.action.todo, and ir.action.client but dont work.

Any idea, using hooks, or other work?

Thanks

Yoinier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to inherit the 'base_import.import' model

```
class Import(models.TransientModel):

    _inherit = 'base_import.import'

    @api.model
    def _convert_import_data(self, fields, options):
        # Override base method
        # Called when actual import start
        data, import_fields = super(Import, self)._convert_import_data(fields, options)

        # Do something ...

        return data, import_fields

    def parse_preview(self, options, count=10):
        # Override base method
        # Called when data loaded
        preview_data = super(Import, self).parse_preview(options, count=count)

        # Do something ...

        return preview_data
```

but, override the base import method is probably not a good idea, I'd suggest to use custom import wizard to do your custom import.

Comment: maybe i need that, a custom import process, i searched but i don't fin any example.

Thanks

Comment: it depend on what you wanted to do in your import

Answer (score 0):

in my case is sampler to you my former developer is edited in odoo15 base_import.now i want to create that into extra addons in odoo17.
check my code ,search_count is execute is even first time(i mean it count after import i want to check before import.

here is my code

```py
class CheckImport(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'base_import.import'
    
    @api.model
    def _convert_import_data(self, fields, options):
        try:
            data, import_fields = super(CheckImport, self)._convert_import_data(fields, options)
            file_name = self.file_name
            same_file = self.env['base_import.import'].search_count([
                ('file_name', '=', file_name), ('res_model', '=', self.res_model), ('file_type', '=', self.file_type)])

            if same_file > 0:
                raise ImportValidationError(_("This File Name is already imported."))

            return data, import_fields
        except ImportValidationError as e:
            raise e
```

Comment: This answer seems a bit unclear and may need some improvement in terms of grammar and structure. The message lacks punctuation, making it harder to follow. Additionally, the technical details provided might need more context or explanation to be fully understood.